# How do I add custom actions to the Base.Actions menu?

Tags: acumatica

In customizations prior to 2021 R1,  I was able to add custom methods to the Actions drop down by using the following:

```
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        Base.actions.AddMenuAction(NewMethod);
    }
```

Now, it looks like there is no such property as Base.actions...    How do I do this now?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the action menu has another name:

```
Base.Action.AddMenuAction(Share);
```

The type `Base.Actions` is not an action type, it is of type `PXActionCollection`.

Possible values are:

- Action
- action
- XyzFolder
- xyzFolder
- etc...

The action name can be different, it depends on the name of the action menu in the graph you are extending.

There has been many changes to action menu with the introduction of the workflow system.
It is now recommended to use the workflow system to add new actions.

Workflow training:
https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/reporting/w150-workflows/

Workflow action configuration, help reference:
https://help-2021r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=cbbac950-4172-42c7-b950-a589a87df249

Comment: Thanks for the reference - I managed to add the action using the Actions screen in the customization project  By the way, there is no such thing as "Base.Action.AddMenuAction..."

Comment: It should depend on the graph extended, some screen have an action menu with that name, some don't.

Answer (score 1):

If action isnt showing, You can create the action category using add the button to it. So in your case.

```
public PXAction<DAC> Actions;

public override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
            Actions.SetCategory("Action");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the section you want in the[PXButton], such as [PXButton(Category = "Other")].

This code is valid in the 2022R2 version I have not tested it on prior versions.

See the image below.

[Adding section to PXButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpuFG.png)